# core.js error on project create with Vue cli

Tags: javascript, vue.js

After i created a project with Vue cli and it give me this error `Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/Desktop/static-web-v1/node_modules/core-js/modules/es.array.iterator.js'` What is wrong and how to fix it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This github issue](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/9474) recommends removing your `node_modules` folder and re-running `npm install`:

`rm -rf node_modules && npm install`

Comment: Thank you It works, but could you explain what causes this issue ? because normally Vue cli works fine but sometimes it has error like this.

Comment: I did as told but the problem persists: open localhost:8080 gives me the exact problem.